# Regex finding any characters in between ( )

Tags: c#, regex

i have a long text and in the text there is many something like this ( hello , hi ) or (hello,hi) , i have to take the space into account . how do i detect them in a long text and retrieve the hello and hi word and add to a list from the text? currently i use this regex :

```
   string helpingWordPattern = "(?<=\\()(.*?)(?<=\\))";
   Regex regexHelpingWord = new Regex(helpingWordPattern);

        foreach (Match m in regexHelpingWord.Matches(lstQuestion.QuestionContent))
       {
           //  removing "," and store helping word into a list
           string str = m.ToString();
           if (str.Contains(","))
           {
                string[] strWords = str.Split(','); // Will contain a ) with a word , e.g. ( whole) ) 

               if(strWords.Contains(")")) 
               {
                   strWords.Replace(")", ""); // Try to remove them. ERROR here cos i can't use array with replace.
               }

                   foreach (string words in strWords)
                   {
                       options.Add(words);
                   }

           }
       }
```

I google and search for the correct regex , the regex i use suppose to remove the ) too but it doesn't .

Comment: Note that you can find text between two parentheses with Regex, but you can never ever match nested parentheses with Regex e.g, `(word1 (word2 (word3)))` (because that would be a context free language, but regular expressions work with regular languages only).

Comment: @Sina "never ever" is a bit harsh. Some engines support this.. such as the .NET engine. They are called Balancing Groups, and are specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this regex pattern:

```
(?<=[\(,])(.*?)(?=[\),])
(?<=[\(,])(\D*?)(?=[\),])  // for anything except number
```

#### Break Up:

```
(?<=[\(,])  = Positive look behind, looks for `(`or `,` 
(.*?)       = Looks for any thing except new line, but its lazy(matches as less as possible)  
(?=[\),])   = Positive look ahead, looks for `)` or `,` after `hello` or `hi` etc.
```

#### [Demo](http://rubular.com/r/PUns9ae64p)

**EDIT**

You can try this sample code for achievement: (untested)

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
MatchCollection mcoll = Regex.Matches(sampleStr,@"(?<=[\(,])(.*?)(?=[\),])")

foreach(Match m in mcoll)
{
    lst.Add(m.ToString());
    Debug.Print(m.ToString());   // Optional, check in Output window.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the `\\(` `\\)` bracket-matchers, outside the group you wish to capture?

```
Regex regex = new Regex( "\\((.*?)\\)");
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches( longText)) {
    string inside = Match.Groups[1];  // inside the brackets.
    ...
}
```

Then use `Match.Groups[1]`, not the whole text of the match.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this... Below is some code using regex to match / split.

```
string input = "txt ( apple , orange) txt txt txt ( hello, hi,5 ) txt txt txt txt";

List Options = new List();

Regex regexHelpingWord = new Regex(@"\((.+?)\)");

foreach (Match m in regexHelpingWord.Matches(input))
{

    string words = Regex.Replace(m.ToString(), @"[()]", "");

    Regex regexSplitComma = new Regex(@"\s*,\s*");


    foreach (string word in regexSplitComma.Split(words))
    {
        string Str = word.Trim();
        double Num;
        bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
        if (!isNum) Options.Add(Str);
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah but i dun wan to detect number in ( ) , anything else but not numbers

Comment: maybe change the second foreach loop

<pre><code>

    foreach (string word in regexSplitComma.Split(words))
    {
        string Str = word.Trim();
        double Num;
        bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
        if (!isNum) Options.Add(Str);
    }

</pre></code>